# Notice: Undefined index: m in C:\xampp\htdocs\votesys\index.php on line 14

Tags: php

I am getting this error and this is the code

```
$m = $_GET['m'];
```

but in web hosting it is working I am getting this error in xampp localhost
I am still checking online on what to do to fix this problem

try to change PHP version from 8 to 7.4 but still getting the error
Hope someone can help me fix this thank you so much.

Comment: Probably in the web hosting the notices are disabled, anyway you should manage the problem in any case. Try: `$m = $_GET['m'] ?? NULL;`